# Css animation is becoming slower and slower with more DOM insertion through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

as the question suggests the page animations become choppy the more DOM i insert in the page dynamically through Javascript. I don't know what is causing the problem or if this is a "normal" behaviour. I might have a memory leak somewhere or some bad code performance.
Thanks 
Edit: some code as requested

```
var somevariable = 40;
var html = [];
for(i = 0; i<somevariable;i++){
    html.push('20 elements');
                        }
                        $("#data-positioner").append(html);
```

The animation that is done later on is not for these inserted elements but for other elements.
This process is repeated on a click event.

Comment: Not certain what Question is? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Exactly how many DOM elements are you inserting? And yeah, a memory leak would definitely slow you down. Might be a good idea to find a way to optimize a smaller number of elements to achieve the same goal.

Comment: We need to see some code... Help us help you.

Comment: @Snowmonkey i alot like 2000

Comment: @DanielD its a lot of code let me grab some of it

Comment: but is it the same animation, or are you actually creating 2000 discrete animation elements? Look at reusing, removing elements when they're no longer needed. Heck -- read about the flyweight pattern! heh.

Comment: What you are describing is normal. Some of the best solutions around the issue imply use of repeater libraries, where only the html elements that fit in the screen are rendered by the browser. Consider using [Clusterize](https://clusterize.js.org/) - not endorsed, but heard good things about it. Feel free to look for alternatives.

Comment: @Snowmonkey The inseted elements are not animated the animations that are getting slow are the ones that were originally loaded with the page

Comment: Thanks @AndreiGheorghiu i will look into it